# Barplot and Binning Issue

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am having trouble producing a meaningful barplot for a project that I am working on in R. This is a sample of the `df` that I am working with.

```
     State JobCode      AverageYearlySalary
2404    CA 15-1031               95820
2408    IN 15-1031               94750
2429    CA 15-2041               85570
2451    NY 15-2041               79300
2452    IN 15-2041               79150
```

Let me outline my struggles to this point. I have tried to organize the values by `JobCode` using: `data1 <- reshape(data, idvar = "JobCode", timevar = "State", direction = "wide")`. I then transform the `df` into a matrix `test <- as.matrix(data1)`. My data type for `JobCode` is a character, which I believe is causing some of my issues. Once done, I use `barplot(test4[,2:4], beside = TRUE)` but always recieve the error `-0.01*height : non-numeric argument to binary operator`.

I want the barplot to organize the individual for `JobCode` on the x-axis and then `AverageYearlySalary` on the y-axis to compare the different states involved. I'm quite new to R and can't figure out a solution after about an hour and a half of google and brute force coding.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make the right matrix for your barplot.

```
XT = xtabs(AverageYearlySalary ~ State + JobCode, data=test4)
barplot(XT, beside=TRUE, col=rainbow(3), ylim=c(0,99000))
legend("topright", legend=rownames(XT), pt.bg=rainbow(3), pch=22)
```

[image: Barplot]

Comment: Hey, @G5W thanks so much for the help. I also over complicate things R for some reason. That example taught me a lot.